# Compass/Sass function & mixin syntax

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm currently writing my first mixin for Compass/Sass. After a short battle, I've got it to generate the exact CSS I need; hence my question isn't about fixing the output, but more about cleaning up the way I've done it.

Here are two snippets of the code I'm using. The complete code generates a `background-image:` CSS rule with any number of comma-separated linear gradients, with `-webkit`, `moz`, and unprefixed gradient declarations in the latest W3C format (using `to top` rather than `bottom`, for example).

As I said, I'm happy with the API and the output. I just want to clean up this code.

Firstly, in the `w3c` conditional block below, how can I avoid what I want:

```
@return linear-gradient($direction, $color-stops);
```

... invoking the built-in Compass `linear-gradient` mixin? (I am including all the CSS3 Compass helpers in my project). All I want is to output a string, interpolating in the values of `$direction` and `$color-stops` inside the parentheses:

```
@function -gradient-rule($type, $direction, $color-stops) {
    @if $type == ('moz') {
        @return -moz-linear-gradient($direction, $color-stops);
    }
    @if $type == ('webkit') {
        @return -webkit-linear-gradient($direction, $color-stops);
    }
    @if $type == ('w3c') {

        // Terrible, terrible hack. Just couldn't work out how to write this without invoking the built-in Compass linear-gradient() function
        $prefix: linear-gradient;
        @return #{$prefix}unquote("(")#{$direction}, #{$color-stops}unquote(")");
    }
}
```

Secondly, is there a cleaner way of writing the code below? I want to loop all the `$gradients`, and for each `$gradient`, assume the first item is a direction declaration, and the rest are colour stops. So the first item should be set in the variable `$to-direction`, and the rest set in a comma-list named `$color-stops`. How can I do this better, i.e. without needing the `$i` counter?

```
@each $gradient in $gradients {

    $i: 1;
    $to-direction: nth($gradient, 1);
    $color-stops: comma-list();

    @each $prop in $gradient {
        @if $i > 1 {
            $color-stops: append($color-stops, $prop);
        }
        $i: $i+1;
    }

    // old syntax is the origin of the gradient, not the destination
    $from-direction: -from-direction($to-direction);
    $moz-value: append($moz-value, -gradient-rule('moz', $from-direction, $color-stops));
    $webkit-value: append($webkit-value, -gradient-rule('webkit', $from-direction, $color-stops));

    // new syntax is the destination
    $w3c-value: append($w3c-value, -gradient-rule('w3c', $to-direction, $color-stops));

    ...
    (continues)
}
```

Many thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the Compass gradient mixin, what does your mixin do that's different?

Comment: Can you throw all of your code up in a [codepen](http://codepen.io/)?  Being able to play around will make things a lot easier : )

Answer (score 1):

1) You can't do much other than interpolate it in quotes. Here's a somewhat cleaner hack:

```
@return #{"linear-gradient("+ $direction +", "+ $color-stops +")"}
```

PS How do you use this code? It's kinda strange to put a

2) Indeed there is a cleaner way!

```
@for $gradient-number from 2 through length($gradients) {
  $gradient: nth($gradients, $gradient-number);

  $to-direction: nth($gradient, 1);
  $color-stops: comma-list();

  @each $prop in $gradient {
    $color-stops: append($color-stops, $prop); }

  ...
```

The `$gradient-number` is basically the same `$i`, so not much of a difference in logic, but a lot of difference in code neatness.

When i first started using this trick i was kinda uncomfy, but then i saw SASS gurus using it too (examples: [1](https://github.com/Snugug/respond-to/blob/master/compass/stylesheets/_respond-to.scss), [2](https://github.com/scottkellum/Singularity/blob/master/stylesheets/singularitygs/helpers/_lists.scss)), so i can recommend it to you without a second thought.